# pdfpages : what does the 'signature' option mean?

Tags: pdfpages

## My issue

I have an A5 pdf that I want to print in order to make a booklet made of folded A4 sheets:

[image: My booklet]
([source](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/printing-booklets.html))

---

## My trials

I use this code to generate the pdf-to-be-printed-as-is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=-, 
            nup=1x2,
            noautoscale,
            signature=16, 
            landscape,
            delta=0 0cm]{myA5pdf}
\end{document}
```

Bonus: a MWE for an 8 pages A5 document

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
        \usepackage[a5paper,twoside]{geometry}
\begin{document}
        \begin{Huge}
        1\clearpage
        2\clearpage
        3\clearpage
        4\clearpage
        5\clearpage
        6\clearpage
        7\clearpage
        8\clearpage
        \end{Huge}
\end{document}
```

However, I think I do not understand the meaning (and the functioning) of the `signature` option.

I have read [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21839/booklet-with-a-specific-page-order-rule) that say:

> **signature** Creates booklets by rearranging pages into signatures and setting nup=1x2 or nup=2x1, respectively. This option takes one argument specifying the size of the signature, which should be a multiple of 4.

but the meaning is then no clearer for me.

---

## My questions

So my questions are:

1. What is the meaning of `signature`?
2. Which argument (multiple of 4) should I chose:

   - when `myA5pdf` has 4*n pages?
   - when `myA5pdf` has 4*n+2 pages?

Comment: Have you done a web search for 'signature' 'book binding'. It might be informative...

Comment: You're right: I had looked for 'signature' + 'pdfpages' only (and you can imagine which results I did got) since I didn't knew that it had a meaning particularly related to bookbinding. But I could have though of it, I was more clever (-;
thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the context of bookbinding, **signature** equals (even if technically incorrect) sections, that are not our beloved hierarchical level #1, but rather booklets that are then stitched together to form a book.
[image: Sections stitched together] ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Stitching_with_dark_sashes.jpg) - you can see here a book made of about 50 *signatures* (i.e. booklets))

In the context of `pdfpages`, the argument of the option `signature` refers to the amount of pages *of the original pdf* you want to have per section (hence a multiple of 4). Here the example of the influence of `signature` when importing a 16 pages document:

[image: 50 shades of signature]

Comment: Great pictures!

Answer (score 6):

Books are traditionally sown in sections which are then joined. Each group of pages sown together is a single signature. So, if your book has 400 pages and each signature contains 8 pages then the book consists of 50 signatures.

For a booklet or short book, you likely have a single signature. So the number of pages in the signature should be the number of pages in the document plus enough empty pages to bring the number up to a multiple of 4.

Hence, if the booklet has 4n pages, use `signature=4n`. If the booklet has (4n+2) pages, use `signtuare=4(n+1)` and 2 additional blank pages will be added to make up the balance.

Comment: I realize this is quite an old answer, but could you elaborate on the 4n/4(n+1) maths here?